Importing a .BIM file in PowerBI desktop
I am working at a hospital and we are looking into using PowerBI as a new reporting tool for storage and sales data(besides the reporting tool that we use for patient data). I had contact with another hospital that already uses PowerBI for this and they were willing to send us their entire model. (Awesome!)
The problem i ran into is that they extracted it into a .BIM file which i am having trouble opening correctly. When i open the BIM. file according to the instructions that i put below, all tables are put into one singular table. So i can see the tablenames etc., they have available but i also really want to see what the relations between the tables are.
I don't have a lot of experience with PowerBI so if anyone can help me out with correctly opening the BIM file in PowerBI desktop would be supper appreciated! if i need any other programs or tools to open the file would also be a big help to know.
The hospital that send us their model is using AZURE as their cloud storage and we are not so that might be the reason why i can't open it correctly.
how i opened the bim file: https://christine-payton.com/bim-files-source-power-bi
enter image description here
